How to type a generic proxy class
How do I tell mypy that my proxy class has the same attributes as the proxied class?
import typing as t
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Proxy(t.Generic[C]):
    def __init__(self, obj: C):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> t.Any:
        return getattr(self.obj, name)


@dataclass
class Data:
    foo: int


pd = Proxy(Data(42))
pd.foo  # this types
pd.oof  # this types too, but it should not

Presumably, mypy sees the __getattr__ method and allows me to query any attribute of my proxy object.  Is it possible to annotate the class Proxy so that it tells mypy to limit available attributes to only those of the proxied class?
EDIT: The important part is that the proxy class needs to be generic; for single case, there are several approaches available as suggested in comments.

There's no way to do that natively, but you can lie to the typechecker (this can be a function or a classmethod): playground. However, if you want to add some attributes from Proxy as well, that's Intersection type which doesn't exist yet - see also basedmypy, and there are many SO questions about type intersection in python.

Duplicates: How to make a proxy object with typing as underlying object in python, Python proxy class with type hints, How to make generic proxy types work with static type checkers.

@InSync You are right that the questions you link are definitely similar, but as far as I can tell, they do not directly apply, especially because they do not deal with generic proxy (the one that does is too different).

@STerliakov I should have thought about a simple approach like that. If you are willing to turn that into an answer, I'm going to accept that, it is good enough for my purpose.

There is also Python Typing: Generic Type that has the same interface as the wrapper type.

@Zephyr That has been already suggested by InSync; in an edit I specified that I am interested in generic proxy, the answer linked by you does not apply.
